# Updating server side Flask sessions with AJAX not working

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, session, flask

I'm trying to figure out why my AJAX script won't update my Flask app's server side session.

Implemented Flask-Session with sqlalchemy. I can see the table in the database and the encrypted session data.

init.py

```
...

from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Session(app)

...
```

config.py

```
...

SESSION_TYPE = 'sqlalchemy'
SESSION_SQLALCHEMY_TABLE = 'app_sessions'
```

Ajax call works as I am getting the correct response.

```
$.post("/ajax_fnc/_update_session", post_data)
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data)
})
```

Flask app returns updated cart_data:

```
...
@app.route('/ajax_fnc/_update_session', methods=['POST'])
def ajax_update_session():

    session['cart_data']['qty'] = 1
    return jsonify(session['cart_data']['qty'])
```

Browser console logs the updated and correct response from the Flask app. But refreshing the site loads the session with a cart data quantity of 0. So it didn't work.

How do I update the server side session with AJAX and get it to persist? What am I missing?

Note: Initializing the session with a cart quantity of 0 on the server side works just fine. Just when I attempt an update with Ajax it doesn't stick. I've spent more than half a day searching for answers but can't seem to find what I'm missing (or not understanding).

Answer (score 0):

Shoot, after a lot more digging it turns out that my initialize function was being called every single time an http request was made. So... of course an ajax update would never persist.

Relocated the initialize function and the server side session works fine.